# warning during javac compilation by ant

Tags: java, ant, compilation, compiler-warnings

I have an ant build for my Java application. I'm forced to make my application be Java 1.6 compatible.

When I run my ant script I get the following warning:

```
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

Can you explain me what does it mean and what should I do to remove it? The code works fine, but I'm going to put it in production and I don't like to leave this kind of warnings unresolved.

My build.xml file looks like this:

```
<path id="master-classpath">
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${bin-dir}" debug="on" source="1.6" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${bin-dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build-dir}"/>

    <delete>
      <fileset dir="${bin-dir}"/>
      <fileset dir="${build-dir}"/>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Ant version: `Ant(TM) version 1.8.2`

Java version: `javac 1.7.0_79`

Comment: Take a look at system environment. Could it be mismatch between JAVA_HOME and java executable (e.g. JAVA_HOME = 1.7, java = 1.8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that although you are using `-source` option, you still have JDK 1.7 library, thus javac cannot guarantee that your code will work on Java 1.6. Javac will check whether you are not using new syntactic features (like `try-with-resources` operator), but it cannot check whether you are using new API methods (like `java.nio.file.Files` class). So even if it's compiled correctly, it may not work.

To my opinion the best solution is to compile with JDK 1.6. What warning suggests you is to provide the custom bootstrap class path which points on the installed JRE 1.6. So you can follow this advice if you have JRE 1.6, but don't want to run the whole build on JDK 1.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My only comment to it: when you have few jdk installed on linux, it does matter where 'java' command points to (javac is apparently ignored by ant task) and it could be configured using: 
update-alternatives --config java

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the javac. See https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source

> To use javac from JDK N to cross-compiler to an older platform
>   version, the correct practice is to:
>
> - Use the older -source setting.
> - Set the bootclasspath to compile against the rt.jar (or equivalent) for the older platform.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your source code or the ANT script you are running to build you application.

It has everything to do with how ANT itself is started. As you have stated you are running Ant using Java 1.7.0_79 There are significant API and library changes between Java 6 and Java 7. To avoid these differences and eliminate the warning you are seeing you need to run ANT in a Java 6 environment.